# Is there a way to use __str__ in a class but returning a list?

Tags: python, string, list, class

When I call a class object, I want it to return a list or any other variable other than string

```
class Vec:
    def __init__(self, data) -> None:
        self.data = data #THIS IS A LIST

    def __str__(self) -> list:
        return self.data

a = Vec([0,1,2,3])
print(a) 

#TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)
```

Instead I get a TypeError, if I set the "self.data" to a string it will work

Is there any Magic Method for this? Thanks in advance

here is the full code in case you need to see it all

note:  I am not done finishing it yet and my problem is that for example if I want to multiply `Mat` with a `Vec` I would have to do `Mat * Vec.data` or `Mat * Vec.T` (T stands for transposed) which I dont like and I would just like to type `Mat * Vec` in case I dont need to transpose the vector. Sorry for my messy code and my bad explanation of my problem

```
class MatrixMatchError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "Matrix sizes do not match"
        super().__init__(self.message)
    pass

class MatrixRowColError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "The number of columns in the first matrix do not equal to the number of rows in the second."
        super().__init__(self.message)
    pass

class Vec:
    def __init__(self, x, identity=1) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.data = self.Create(x, 1, identity)
        self.T = self.Transpose()

    def Create(self, x, y, identity) -> list:
        vec = []
        for i in range(y):
            vec.append([])
            for j in range(x):
                vec[i].append(identity)

        return vec

    def Transpose(self) -> list:
        vec = self.Create(len(self.data), len(self.data[0]), 0)
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            for j in range(len(self.data[0])):
                vec[j][i] = self.data[i][j]

        return vec

class Mat:
    def __init__(self, x, y=0, identity=1) -> None:
        self.x = x
        if y == 0:
            self.y = x
        else:
            self.y = y

        self.data = self.Create(self.x, self.y, identity)
        self.T = self.Transpose()

    def __add__(self, data):
        if not self.CheckSize(data):
            raise MatrixMatchError

        mat3 = self.data.copy()
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            for j in range(len(self.data[0])):
                mat3[i][j] = self.data[i][j] + data[i][j]

        return mat3

    def __sub__(self, data):
        if not self.CheckSize(data):
            raise MatrixMatchError

        mat3 = self.data.copy()
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            for j in range(len(self.data[0])):
                mat3[i][j] = self.data[i][j] - data[i][j]

        return mat3

    def __mul__(self, data):
        if not self.CheckRowCol(data):
            raise MatrixRowColError

        mat3 = self.Create(len(data[0]), len(self.data),  0)

        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            for j in range(len(data[0])):
                for k in range(len(self.data[0])):
                    mat3[i][j] += self.data[i][k] * data[k][j]

        return mat3

    def Create(self, x, y, identity) -> list:
        mat = []
        for i in range(y):
            mat.append([])
            for j in range(x):
                mat[i].append(0)

        if x == y:
            for i in range(x):
                mat[i][i] = identity

        return mat

    def Transpose(self) -> list:
        mat = self.Create(len(self.data), len(self.data[0]), 0)
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            for j in range(len(self.data[0])):
                mat[j][i] = self.data[i][j]

        return mat

    def CheckSize(self, data):
        if len(self.data) != len(data) or len(self.data[0]) != len(data[0]):
            return False
        return True

    def CheckRowCol(self, data):
        if len(data) != len(self.data[0]):
            return False
        return True

    def Transform(self):
        pass

    def Scale(self):
        pass

    def Rotate(self):
        pass
        

mat1 = Mat(2)
mat1.data = [[4,5, 4],
            [9,3, 7],
            [7,1, 3]]

vec = Vec(3)
print(mat1 * vec.T)
```

Comment: What do you expect the output of print(a) to be?

Comment: Why would you even want to introduce such a behavior? __str__  has got it's name for a reason, sounds like big code smell

Comment: I want it to return a list

Comment: @Jastcher then write a different method for the intended purpose or convert the list to a string before returning it

Comment: `__str__` returns a string. It can be a string constructed *from* a list, but it still has to be a string, not the list itself.

Comment: because I am working on a matrix and vector classes, and when I want to work with the data, I dont want to type a.data all the time, and this can be done in c++ some way so that is why I am asking

Comment: @Bialomazur but you cant conver the string back to a list. Or can you?

Comment: So you should not use `__str__` method. It returns string.

Comment: What is it you have in mind that you can do in C++?

Comment: @Jastcher you actually can, simply use **eval** on the returned String and convert the string back to a list-object. I can write a concrete code-implementation in an answer if you like.

Comment: @Jastcher this feels like an "XY problem".  You should show a code snippet illustrating how you want to use this class, and then it'll be easier to tell you how to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Bialomazur get thee behind me, Satan

Comment: @Samwise Whut x)

Comment: @Jastcher as much as I understood, you do not want to type `a.data` every time, right? However, `__str__` method is not intended for such a use. Personally, I do not see any problem using standard `a.data` syntax since that is how OOP works.

Comment: You can make `Vec` a *subclass* of `list`, so that you don't need a separate `data` attribute at all. That might create more problems than it solves, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin `str()` function will raise a `TypeError` if it calls your `__str__` and gets something that isn't a string, and you won't convince it to do otherwise.

What you probably want is for `Vec.__str__` to return the string representation of `data`, rather than `data` itself:

```
class Vec:
    def __init__(self, data: list) -> None:
        self.data = data

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.data)
```

The `__str__` method has no bearing on your other use case:

> for example if I want to multiply `Mat` with a `Vec` I would have to do `Mat * Vec.data` or `Mat * Vec.T` (T stands for transposed) which I dont like and I would just like to type `Mat * Vec` in case I dont need to transpose the vector.

This should instead be addressed in `Mat.__mul__` (which should operate on a `Vec`, not the underlying `list`) and `Vec.T`/`Vec.Transpose` (which should return a `Vec`, not a `list`):

```
class Vec:

    ...

    def Transpose(self) -> 'Vec':
        vec = self.Create(len(self.data), len(self.data[0]), 0)
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            for j in range(len(self.data[0])):
                vec[j][i] = self.data[i][j]
        return Vec(vec)


class Mat:
    ...

    def __mul__(self, vec: Vec) -> list[list[int]]:
        if not self.CheckRowCol(vec.data):
            raise MatrixRowColError

        mat3 = self.Create(len(vec.data[0]), len(self.data),  0)

        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            for j in range(len(vec.data[0])):
                for k in range(len(self.data[0])):
                    mat3[i][j] += self.data[i][k] * vec.data[k][j]

        return mat3
```

Now you can indeed do `Mat * Vec` or `Mat * Vec.T` and it will do the right thing.

Note that it would probably be better for `Mat.__mul__` to return a `Mat`, but you haven't provided a constructor that makes it easy for me to implement that part -- nevertheless I hope this gives you a better way to think about your class interfaces and how they can make it easier (or harder) to use the class!  Ideally the user of the class shouldn't even be *able* to access the internals, much less be forced to.

Unrelated to this, I'd suggest spending a bit of time learning about Python's list comprehension syntax, because it'll save you a lot of list allocation boilerplate (i.e. your various `Create` methods).  :)

Comment: but how do I convert the string back to a list

Comment: Why would you need to???  `self.data` is still a list.  Are you sure this `Vec` class even needs to exist?  It sounds like you just want to use a plain old list.

Comment: but when you return in with __str__ it will be a string

Comment: Yes.  **It needs to be a string or str() will raise.  str() by definition must always either return a string or raise an exception.  This is built into the language.**  Whatever reason you think you have for getting `str()` to return a list, I assure you it is not a thing.  I'm pretty sure you don't need your `Vec` class at all.

Comment: In what context would you expect `__str__` to be called where you would need to parse the result back to a list?

Comment: but then I cant do custom operations like __add__ or __mul__ or __sub__

Comment: @Jastcher your `Vec` class doesn't implement any of those methods.  If you edit your question to demonstrate how you plan to use this class, including how you plan to use `str` that makes it necessary for it to return a `list`, you will get *much more helpful answers*.  The right approach might be to subclass `list`, or it might be to wrap `list` as you're doing and implement other magic methods that will delegate to `self.data` where needed.  It's impossible to say without knowing what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: but there is still nothing that compels ‘str’ to return a list.

Comment: @quamrana ok I dont want to use the str method because it does not work, and my main qiestion was if there is any other magic method that solves my problem

Comment: also there is still everything compelling about having str return a string. Then print() can render a Vec or Mat.

Comment: @Jastcher Added a bit more to my answer.  You already have the magic methods that solve this problem, the only thing you need to change is the way you think about their type signatures.